# Client USB device driver query

Tags: windows, usb, driver

How does an OS maps USB device with its device driver? I understand that in the interface descriptor of client USB firmware if no class type has been selected for the device then developer has to provide its own device driver.

I am keen to know how OS maps the pluggged USB device with its device driver? Does descriptors in the USB client firmware contains the file name of the custom device driver? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hobby, [I have done quite a bit of work with the USB hardware](http://www.fysnet.net/the_universal_serial_bus.htm), and had these same questions when I first started.

An OS can map a USB device any way it wants.  However, to be more precise toward your question, a USB device will, and must return a class and interface code.  Granted, that class code can be 0xFF for user-defined, where the device now must require a unique driver.

In my opinion, this is where the USB shines.  All USB devices that return a valid class code specified within the USB specification, will and must follow a specific sequence of events and will "work right out of the box" as indicated.  However, this doesn't mean that it cannot have extra capabilities.

For example.  A pointing device, such as a mouse, will probably always follow the boot protocol when first plugged in.  This is the protocol used and specified in the USB specification so that any OS that follows this protocol can use this pointing device.  This protocol specifies a simple three (or more) byte packet for pointer input.

```
Byte   Description
 0       Button(s)
 1       X Displacement
 2       Y Displacement
 3       (Device Specific) (optional)
```

Any pointing device that follows the USB specification most likely has this protocol and will use this protocol until told otherwise.  This is so any USB capable OS can use the pointing device.

Every USB device also has a vendor, device, and protocol definition.  Once the OS has found this device, it can search through its drivers for a driver that can support this device.  That driver, once loaded, can then tell the device to now use a different protocol.  i.e.:  Return a different Input Report.

Here is an example.  Let's say that you have a fancy gaming mouse with three directions of displacement (X, Y and Z), and six buttons.  As the OS is booting, it probably has no idea how to use that mouse.  Therefore, the manufacturer creates the mouse to use the boot protocol shown above until the driver can be loaded.  Once the driver is loaded, which knows how to use the three direction displacements and all six buttons, it can tell the mouse, through a Control packet, maybe the SET INTERFACE command as well, to now start sending a different report, now using the full capabilities of the mouse.

So, as along as the device is USB specification accurate, *and* has a class code not of user defined (0xFF), the device will be recognized, even if it is a minimal use and/or is to show a statement that a driver is needed.

As for giving a file name of a custom device driver, this is all up to the device manufacturer.  However, usually this is not that case.  Usually, the OS will retrieve the DEVICE DESCRIPTOR which contains the manufacturer, device, protocol, and other fields.  It will then match any driver to those fields.  If it does not find a compatible driver, it will ask for one.

For example, one of the pointing devices I used with my research has the following few bytes of the 18-byte Device Descriptor:

```
  Offset   Field       Value
     0    Length       0x12
     1    Type         0x01
     2    Release Num  0x0110
     4    Device Class 0x00
     5    Sub Class    0x00
     6    Protocol     0x00
     7    MaxPacketSz  0x08
     8    VendorID     0x04FC
    10    Product ID   0x0003
    ...
```

Notice that it specifies the Vendor and the Product.  Using these two values, a compatible driver can be found.

Now, notice that the class code is zero.  This is not an error and is a perfectly valid class code, and simply means that the interface descriptor is to be used instead.

So, hopefully with this information, and specifically, the Manufacturer and Product codes within the DEVICE DESCRIPTOR, you can now see how an OS can find the correct driver for any device.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. To summarize can I say that class code of 0xFF makes use of boot code and class code of 0x00 makes use of interface descriptor for OS to communicate with USB device. Is this what you mean?

Comment: A class code of 0xFF means that the device is vender-specific.  i.e.:  The OS does not have to support the device at all--a custom driver is required.  All other values mean the device might be and probably is supported by the OS, though most likely in its minimal form.